# How can I make Fedora 12 run faster?

Tags: fedora, fedora-12

I recently installed Fedora 12 on my machine. I think it's the fastest Fedora version I've used. But I was wondering whether I could make it run faster than it already is.

Comment: What part of it feels slow to you? Or is this a really vague performance question?

Comment: It's not slow. It's fast. I just want to make it faster in ways that is not possible with the default installation.

Answer (score 3):

It probably feels sluggish because of the default desktop environment (GNOME) which uses a fair amount of memory. You can easily change your desktop environment though. I'd recommend [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) for a full DE, or if you really want to use minimal resources, a lightweight window manager such as the *Box variants ([Fluxbox](http://www.fluxbox.org/), [OpenBox](http://icculus.org/openbox/index.php/Main_Page), [BlackBox](http://blackboxwm.sourceforge.net/)), or [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/) on top of X itself would be good. It doesn't have to look horrifying either, here's a screenshot of openbox:

[image]